# C++ - Convert any number of nested vector of vector to equivalent vector of span

Tags: c++

following situation: I work with data that falls into the categories of

```cpp
std::vector<T> data1;
std::vector<std::vector<T>> data2;
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<T>>> data3; //etc...
```

T usually refers to numerical data like `double`.
Sometimes I would like to get the data in a form where the last `std::vector` is replaced by a `std::span<T>` pointing to the same data.

```cpp
std::span<T> data1;
std::vector<std::span<T>> data2;
std::vector<std::vector<std::span<T>>> data3; //etc...
```

It's not hard to define individual functions for every single level of nesting, but could I somehow also define a single function that could do this automatically for any level of nesting?

Comment: But `std::span` in not an owner of its data. When original `std::vector` will be removed - `std::span` will be no longer valid

Comment: Yes, the spans are only used for temporary calculations while the underlying data is definitely valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
auto transform(std::vector<T>& v, F func)
{
    std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(func(v[0]))>> res;
    res.reserve(v.size());
    std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(res), func);
    return res;
}

template <typename T>
std::span<T> to_span(std::vector<T>& v)
{
    return v;
}

template <typename T>
auto to_span(std::vector<std::vector<T>>& v)
{
    return transform(v, [](auto& inner){ return to_span(inner); });
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rWh5G3qTo)

Comment: The additional indirection through the `tranform` function seems a bit unnecessary. Also, span can take a vector directly. https://godbolt.org/z/8Mrd3jhdv

Comment: I believe this answer works and I realize what is happening, interesting stuff. I have also tested ur answer, @cigien, and it definitely works and is a bit easier to follow aswell. Thank you!